# mask after finding shape's contour

Tags: node.js, opencv, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I'm trying to write ANPR project in `nodejs`.

I managed to draw the contours around the license plate, but now I want to mask it.

this is what I got now (just without the text):

[image]

i want to mask it like so (and even crop it afterwards):

[image]

this is my code by now:

```
import cv from 'opencv4nodejs';

// read image, grayscale
const img = cv.imread('./images/img2.jpg');
const grayImg = img.bgrToGray();

const bfilter = grayImg.bilateralFilter(11, 17, 17);
const edged = bfilter.canny(30, 200);

const getContour = (handMask) => {
    const mode = cv.RETR_TREE;
    const method = cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE;
    const contours = handMask.findContours(mode, method);

    return contours
        .sort((c0, c1) => c1.area - c0.area)
        .slice(0, 10)
        .find((contour) => {
            const x = contour.approxPolyDP(10, true);
            return x.length === 4;
        });
};
let edgeContour = getContour(edged);

let mask = new cv.Mat(grayImg.rows, grayImg.cols, 0, 0);

let x = img.drawContours([edgeContour.getPoints()], 0, new cv.Vec3(0, 255, 0), {
    thickness: 5,
});

x = img.bitwiseAnd(img);
cv.imshow('drawContours', x);

cv.waitKey();
```

Comment: Drawtje contour woth thickness -1 and show the image.

Comment: @Micka it fills the license plate